# Easiest way to deploy a website and database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, deployment, web-deployment

It's difficult to know which technology to use when deploying a website/database project, Web Deploy, Direct Publish, Web Setup Projects, Wix.. lots of options and they all seem overly complicated yet overly simplified at the same time.

I have a common scenario though, I have a web site (actually a web service) and a database to deploy with the following requirements.

- must be able to update database with future releases safely without data loss
- must install the website to `C:\Program Files\<Company_Name>\<Website_Name>`
- installing user must provide the database location which is used to install the DB and set the connection string in web.config file
- must add a permissions for the Application Pool of the website to access the Database
- **UPDATE:** must produce a binary deployment package which can be deployed to intranets without an internet connection

Can anyone offer guidance on which technology I should focus on, I'm looking for something easy to use as I don't have much time to package my project. Also any guidance on achieving the last 2 of my requirements in perticular would be great.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Generally these tasks are best served by installer generators such as Wix or InstallShield. I'd recommend Wix,it's very powerful and customizable.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat Will I be able to meet all my requirements using Wix?

Comment: Yes. But not everything may come as part of the Wix package. You may have to write your own code for some of the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's nice to use GIT (Check Git hub) as a repository with version control. You can set it up to make automatic deploys into the server. My Git Hub is configured to deploy automatically into Application Harbor, which I love. It is free and it gives you a 20mb database.

The url you get is not so bad: http://yourapplication.apphb.com

https://appharbor.com/

https://github.com/

Comment: I do need a binary deployment package, the website and database that I'm deploying will be used multiple times at many different company sites (not all of whom allow their intranet servers access to the internet). Thanks for your answer though, I will update my requirements.

Comment: I see... you did well to include that detail on your requirements